# MUI Breadcrumbs with React Router - customise breadcrumb labels

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

Here, the implementation that I have on breadcrumbs with MUI and React router.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Breadcrumbs as AppBreadcrumbs,
  Link,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {
  const {
    history,
    location: { pathname },
  } = props;

  const pathnames = pathname.split("/").filter((x) => x);

  return (
    <AppBreadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <Link onClick={() => history.push("/")}>Home</Link>
      {pathnames.map((name, index) => {
        const goTo = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join("/")}`;
        const active = index === pathnames.length - 1;
        return active ? (
          <Typography>{name}</Typography>
        ) : (
          <Link onClick={() => history.push(goTo)}>{name}</Link>
        );
      })}
    </AppBreadcrumbs>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Breadcrumbs);
```

Everything works as expected but I'm having problem with the labels for the breadcrumbs.
I have these 3 pages with their links like so : `"book-table"`, `"food-delivery"`, `"sponsor"`

And this is how they show up on my pages:

```
Home / book-table
Home / food-delivery
Home / sponsor
```

How can I have a custom the label for each of the breadcrumb like so?
If it's on `book-table` page, it will show like this : `Home / Book a Table`. If it's on `food-delivery`, it will show like this: `Home / Order Food` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no clear pattern that you can use to transform the path name I would suggest creating a config object and iterate over it, for example:

```js
const routes = [{
  path: '/book-table',
  title: 'Book Table'
}]

return routers.map(x => return <SomeBreadcumb route={x.route}>{x.title}</SomeBreadcumb>)
```

This way your code will be cleaner, more readable and more maintainable. For example: you might want to change the title according to user's language preferences and in this way it'll be easier than the approach you decided to take.

Hope that helps